# How to create an inner array inside parent array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I'm a newbie to the complicated arrays in PHP. 
I'm having an associative array named `$questions` as follows(For your reference I'm printing only first two elements of this associative array, the actual array is too large):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33185
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => Two gases are at 300 K and 350 K respectively Ratio of average kinetic energy of their molecules is
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180210
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 
            [question_updated_date] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_id] => 33187
            [question_parent_id] => 0
            [question_subject_id] => 4
            [question_topic_id] => 503
            [question_directions] => 
            [question_text] => what will be the temperature when the rms velocity is double the rms velocity at 300 K
            [question_file] => 
            [question_description] => 
            [question_difficulty_type] => 1
            [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
            [question_picked_individually] => no
            [question_appeared_count] => 0
            [question_manual] => 0
            [question_site_id] => 
            [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
            [question_added_date] => 1328180274
            [question_updated_staff_id] => 
            [question_updated_date] => 0
        )
)
```

Now my manipulation code over this array is as follows:

```
/*Compare each question with all the questions present within an array*/
            foreach ($questions as $outer_data) {

        $outer_question = $outer_data['question_text'];

        foreach ($questions as $inner_data) {

          $inner_question = $inner_data['question_text'];  

            $same_chars = similar_text($outer_question, $inner_question, $percent);
            $percentage = number_format((float)$percent, 2, '.', '');

            if($percentage > 50) {
                //I'm not able to write a perfect code to create an array here, please help me out in writing this code
            }
        }
      }
```

In the above code I've written a comment over there where I'm facing a problem. 
Actually I want to attach all the question ids to the original array `$questions` when if condition(i.e. `$percentage > 50`) gets satisfied. Suppose for question id 33185 following ids have similar questions then the array element having question_id value as 33185 should look like as follows:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [question_id] => 33185
                [question_parent_id] => 0
                [question_subject_id] => 4
                [question_topic_id] => 503
                [question_directions] => 
                [question_text] => Two gases are at 300 K and 350 K respectively Ratio of average kinetic energy of their molecules is
                [question_file] => 
                [question_description] => 
                [question_difficulty_type] => 1
                [question_has_sub_ques] => 0
                [question_picked_individually] => no
                [question_appeared_count] => 0
                [question_manual] => 0
                [question_site_id] => 
                [question_created_staff_id] => fbfee12504bf3c4a038d4c9f142f894e
                [question_added_date] => 1328180210
                [question_updated_staff_id] => 
                [question_updated_date] => 0
                [similar_questions_ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60905
                    [1] => 60929
                    [2] => 60912
                )


            )
)
```

Now I'm facing an issue in writing the perfect code for this desired output. If I've written the present code in a wrong way, you can imrovize it as I'm a newbie to arrays in PHP. Any kind of suggestion will be welcomed. Can anyone help me in this regard, please? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A good question because you posted all the information needed... :-)
My attempt at an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outside loop, initialise the array

```php
$outer_data['similar_questions_id'] = Array();
```

In the inner loop, add to the array if the percentage is exceeded...

```
$outer_data['similar_questions_id'][] = $inner_question['question_id'];
```

I'm not sure why you do the funky number format on the percentage; I don't think its needed. Compare to 50.0 if floats are the problem here.

**Idea:** It is possible that you don't need to go through the entire array in the inner loop. You could improve performance by noting that if one question is similar to another the reverse should be true also and assign both percentages at the same time. Your inner loop only needs to scan from the index your outer loop has got to.

```
foreach ($questions as $i => &$outer_data) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < length($questions); $j++) {
        $inner_data = &$questions[$j];
        ....
    }
}
```

I believe that the foreach loops have to reference the array elements (using &) as they need to modify the array...

Comment: :Thanks for your answer and valuable suggestion. Could you please help me in implementing the idea you suggested to me, please?

Comment: You'll have to take it from there or find someone with more free time - I'm at work :'(

Comment: :No issues, whenever you get time please try to give me the optimum code. Till then I'll try on my behalf. Thanks for your help once again.